# I cannot use more than one font in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This sounds like a stupid question, but I can't get it to work.

```
from pygame import *
from random import *
from math import *
import os
from datetime import datetime
#importing all needed modules
mixer.init() #initializing mixer for sound use
init() #initializing pygame
font.init() #Just to prove that it still doesn't work
SCREEN = (1000,700)
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(350, 25)
screen = display.set_mode(SCREEN)

font = font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 52)
font2 = font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 12)
```

the first one works but the second one throws an error:
builtins.AttributeError: 'pygame.font.Font' object has no attribute 'SysFont'

been having this problem and need to use fonts because I need to blit a variable that changes.

Comment: You've declared `font`, there for you can't call `font.SysFont` right after. Since `font` is no longer a `pygame` call, it's become a font object returned by `font.SysFont(...)`. One way you can detect these issues in the future (you're bound to do it again), is by doing `print(font)` in between both `Times New Roman` "creations". You'll quickly find out what font is and it won't be the thing you expect it to be. That's a good way to learn and debug your own code before tearing your hair out or asking SO when in fact it's a simple typing issue :) It happens to all of us, learning by doing.

Comment: As the first comment says, you need to be more careful about your names. Don't use a system name as a variable name, for example, which is what tripped you up here. Also, don't use the `from pygame import *` style of imports. This can cause a collision of names that are the same in various modules. This style is meant only for use at the console, where you do this for only one module. Don't use it multiple times, and don't use it in a program.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Torxed

Answer (score 0):

you declared font as a variable in the first line, you need to change it to font1 or some facsimile of such